# What are good travel game apps for iPad to entertain a 2-3 year old

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, games, children

My wife is to face a 2h flight with our very active daughter and would like to prepare some distractions.

Specifically we are looking for very simple, entertaining games a toddler can handle. We already have "Memory" and she really enjoys it.

It should be as colorful as it can get and interactive where swiping and touching a thing is the most sophisticated gesture she can handle. Doesn't really have to have a goal, just do stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of apps for children. You can find some decent apps [here](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/10-best-ipad-apps-for-kids-937546) and [here](http://www.bestkidsapps.com/), or just by using the terms "iPad app Children" in Google :-)
Enjoy you flight!

Comment: Goodluck with the flight and the children! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is an iPhone app, but will work on iPad, It is a game made for toddlers.

http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/bubbles